# Registration of non-Java App following Eureka API Documentation - Issue

Tags: netflix-eureka

I have Eureka running in my localhost:8090 . I have independent Java Apps registered in that Eureka and I am able to access them with my Zuul URL which is registered to that Eureka as well.

Now I am have another Python(3.7.3)+Flask App that I am trying to register in same Eureka and access that through same Zuul URL. 
My Python app runs fine in local through a DOCKERFILE with these commands -

```
EXPOSE 8443
CMD ["python", "PythonFlaskSample.py"]
```

This opens a web-page with this URL - 
http://localhost:8443/home

Then to register this App in Eureka, I followed this documentation -

https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations 
and 
https://automationrhapsody.com/json-format-register-service-eureka/

Also trying same through REST clients with POST URL as -
http://localhost:8090/eureka/v2/apps/PythonFlaskApp
Content-Type: application/json

```
{
    "instance": {
        "hostName": "localhost",
        "app": "PythonFlaskSample",
        "vipAddress": "localhost",
        "secureVipAddress": "localhost",
        "ipAddr": "<Which IP>????",
        "status": "STARTING",
        "port": {"$": "8090", "@enabled": "true"},
        "securePort": {"$": "8443", "@enabled": "true"},
        "healthCheckUrl": "http://localhost:8090/health",
        "statusPageUrl": "http://localhost:8090/info",
        "homePageUrl": "http://localhost:8090",
        "dataCenterInfo": {
            "@class": "com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo", 
            "name": "MyOwn"
        },
    }
}
```

But it is throwing a 405 and no other clue for what happened in Restlet client or Postman.

When I try to put the JSON Payload in python file and use POST from there,

```
request_body = {
    "instance": {
        "hostName": "localhost",
        "app": "PythonFlaskSample",
        "vipAddress": "localhost",
        "secureVipAddress": "localhost",
        "ipAddr": "<Which IP>????",
        "status": "STARTING",
        "port": {"$": "8090", "@enabled": "true"},
        "securePort": {"$": "8443", "@enabled": "true"},
        "healthCheckUrl": "http://localhost:8090/health",
        "statusPageUrl": "http://localhost:8090/info",
        "homePageUrl": "http://localhost:8090",
        "dataCenterInfo": {
            "@class": "com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo", 
            "name": "MyOwn"
        },
    }
}

data=json.dumps(request_body)
url="http://localhost:8090"
response = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(request_body), headers = {'Content-type':'application/json'}).json()

print(response)
```

it shows following error-

> docker run -p 8443:8443 dockerpython {'timestamp': 1555717403333,
>   'status': 405, 'error': 'Method Not Allowed', 'exception':
>   'org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException',
>   'message': "Request method 'POST' not supported", 'path': '/'}

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error with Eureka API documentation in - https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations. Once I tried same REST URLs without "/v2" , everything worked fine.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDwq2.png)